# ($('.class-name').is(":checked")) Never True

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have placed a few checkboxes using a loop. Here is the PHP code that generates the loop:

```
<form class="small-box-footer" style="text-align:left;padding:10px;"  method="post" name="nameHere">
    <?php
    while ($row39 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $Referrer_ID = $row39['Subject_ID'];
        $Referrer_Name = $row39['Subject_Name'];
    ?>
        <input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="<?= $Referrer_ID ?>"> <?= $Referrer_Name ?><?= $Referrer_ID ?><br />        
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

In the following snippet is the HTML that gets generated from this PHP code and the JavaScript code that creates a link if the checkbox is checked; The issue is that the if condition is not getting true:

```js
      $( ".centre-selection" ).each(function() {
  $( this ).attr( "href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject='+ $('.subject-selected').val()+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-all-centre')) +'&StartDate='+$('#report_date_start').val()+'&EndDate=18/12/2016');

  
   } );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="2"> GCSE Maths2<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="3"> GCSE English3<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="4"> GCSE Science4<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="5"> GCSE Art5<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="6"> GCSE Sociology6<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="8"> OCR Nationals ICT8<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="9"> OCR Nationals Sports9<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="10"> OCR Nationals Business Studies10<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="11"> Entry Science11<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="12"> Functional Skills English12<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="13"> Functional Skills Maths13<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="14"> ESOL14<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="subject-selected"  name="subject" value="15"> Preparation for Working Life15<br />
```

EDIT:

I think the question is not getting understood properly. Below is the first JavaScript I wrote,

```
$( ".centre-selection" ).each(function() {
            //$( this ).attr( 'href', '?module=<?=$_REQUEST['module']?>&Subject='+ $( this ).attr('data-subject')+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ $( this ).attr('data-centre')+ '&Class_Selected_Year='+ $( this ).attr('data-year')+ '&Class_Selected_All='+ $( this ).attr('data-all-centre')+ '&StartDate='+ $( this ).attr('report_date_start')+ '&EndDate='+ $( this ).attr('data-attendance-check-end'));
            $( this ).attr( "href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject='+ $('.subject-selected').val()+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All='+ encodeURIComponent($( this ).attr('data-all-centre')) +'&StartDate='+$('#report_date_start').val()+'&EndDate=18/12/2016');
          } );
```

The above JavaScript worked but the value of subject selected was always '2' which is the first subject.

Comment: Format the script please...

Comment: Please use a tool like codepen, it's easy and help a lot.

Comment: May be you want to get which checked box you changed.

Comment: `$('.subject-selected').each(........)` and and that this.checked...

Comment: `$('.subject-selected')` will select ALL of your checkboxes. Is that what you want??

Comment: Add a `$('.subject-selected').change(function() { ... });` method.

Answer (score 3):

Try something ,

```
// loop only for checked checkboxes
$('.subject-selected:checked').each(function(){
    a=$(this).next('a'); // get the next anchor element
    a.length && a.attr( "href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject='+ this.value+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ encodeURIComponent(a.attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year='+ encodeURIComponent(a.attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All='+ encodeURIComponent(a.attr('data-all-centre')) +'&StartDate='+$('#report_date_start').val()+'&EndDate=18/12/2016');
 });
```

As, per @Fahad comment

```
// loop for all checkboxes
$('.subject-selected').each(function(){
    a=$(this).next('a'); // get the next anchor element
    if(this.checked){
       a.length && a.attr( "href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject='+ this.value+ '&Centre_Selected_ID='+ encodeURIComponent(a.attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year='+ encodeURIComponent(a.attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All='+ encodeURIComponent(a.attr('data-all-centre')) +'&StartDate='+$('#report_date_start').val()+'&EndDate=18/12/2016');
    } else {
        // not checked code here
    }
 });
```

Updated for anchor tag loop, the reason of getting only `2` every time is because you are using `$('.subject-selected').val()` and jquery will return the first checkbox element. So, you need to use anchor tag index to get its equivalent checkbox value.

```
$( ".centre-selection" ).each(function(index) {
     $( this ).attr( "href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject='+ 
       $('.subject-selected:eq('+index+')').val()+ ....);
});
```

Comment: I don't want to loop only for checked boxes. I want every result to be a link but I want to check first that the checked value is getting stored.

Comment: The links are still not being generated.

Comment: The problem is not here. The real problem is that the checkbox's value is not getting selected. If it was getting selected I would have directly made every item a link. the if statement wouldn't have been needed.

Comment: So, how you want to populate the values of `$(this).attr('data-all-centre')`, `$(this).attr('data-year')` and `$(this).attr('data-centre')`. You can also apply click event on checkbox so that the links can be changed dynamically.

Comment: The checkbox is different and the item on which links are being generated are different.

Comment: Show us your full HTML code i.e. checkbox with anchor elements , so that we can help you more for this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112766/discussion-between-rohan-kumar-and-fahad-uddin).

Answer (score 2):

You have to loop through all `subject-selected` like this:

```
$('.subject-selected').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).attr("href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject=' + $("input[type='checkbox']").val() + '&Centre_Selected_ID=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-all-centre')) + '&StartDate=' + $('#report_date_start').val() + '&EndDate=18/12/2016');
    }
});
```

Comment: logically and syntactically the values are undefined and incorrect `$(this).attr('data-year')`, `$(this).attr('data-all-centre')` and `$("input[type='checkbox']").val()`. try to correct if you giving any answer to SO.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".subject-selected").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //Do stuff
    }
});
```

Try something like this

Answer (score 0):

You need add a event listener to each "input" to capture the event (click or change or whatever).

Try:

```
$('.subject-selected').each(function(){
  $(this).on('click',function(e){
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ){
    $(this).attr("href", '?module=module_progress_report&Subject=' + $("input[type='checkbox']").val() + '&Centre_Selected_ID=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-centre')) + '&Class_Selected_Year=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-year')) + '&Class_Selected_All=' + encodeURIComponent($(this).attr('data-all-centre')) + '&StartDate=' + $('#report_date_start').val() + '&EndDate=18/12/2016');
    }
  });
});
```